# Getting data out of Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following structure:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="myDiv1">
    <ul>
      <li>Abc</li>
      <li>Def</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="myDiv2">
    <ul>
      <li>Ghi</li>
      <li>Jkl</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

There can be several `myDivX`.

I want to get some information out of it in the following way:

```
myDiv1
Abc
Def
myDiv2
Ghi
Jkl
```

This is my approach:

```
$("#main").each(function() {
  $("div").each(function() {
    console.log(this.id)
  });
  $("ul").each(function() {
    console.log(this)
  });
});
```

It gives me this:

```
main
myDiv1
myDiv2
<ul>​<li>​Abc​</li>​<li>​Def​</li>​</ul>​
<ul>​<li>​Ghi​</li>​<li>​Jkl​</li>​</ul>​
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xqu8fpwm/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/xqu8fpwm/1/)

```js
$('#main div').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
  $(this).find('li').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Run a Depth-First-Search in-order traversal on the sub-DOM tree under div#main.

Nick Zakas has a great article on how to write this function in Javascript: https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/09/computer-science-in-javascript-binary-search-tree-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div").each(function() {
    If($(this).attr("id").indexOf("myDiv") < 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    console.log(this.id)
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're proposed solution is recommending.